# Sumar contenido de un array en python

Tags: python, array

Me encontré con un inconveniente al intentar sumar el contenido de un array en python, el codigo es el siguiente:

```
  n=3;suma=0
    for i in range(n):
        print("Se van ingresando",i,"valores de",n,"valores")
        print("Ingrese valores que desee..")
        A=[int(input("Valores: "))]
    suma=sum(A)
    print(suma)
```

El problema esta en:

```
A=[int(input("Valores: "))]
```

Python lo está tomando como "string" y no como "int".
El error es el siguiente:

```
File "SumaArray.py", line 16, in <module>
    suma=sum(A)
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

¿como seria correctamente?

Comment: Por que haces `suma(A)`, `suma` no es una función, creo que te refieres a `sum()`. Además estás reescribiendo `A` por cada ciclo. Intenta con `A[i] = int(input("Valores: "))`, y definir `A = []` fuera del ciclo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La instrucción

```
A=[int(input("Valores: "))]
```

pide un valor por teclado, lo convierte a entero y lo transforma en una lista de un solo elemento, que asigna a la variable `A`.

Por tanto, en cada pasada reemplazas `A` con una nueva lista de un solo elemento.

Lo que tienes que hacer es 1) Inicializar la lista `A` fuera del `for`, y 2) agregar cada valor a la lista `A` usando `append()`.

El código correcto es:

```
n = 3
A = []
for i in range(n):
    print("Se van ingresando", i, "valores de", n, "valores")
    print("Ingrese valores que desee..")
    valor = int(input("Valores: "))
    A.append(valor)

suma = sum(A)
print(suma)
```